# How to do greater than/less than conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, cfml

I am having issues when trying to use a greater than and less than conditional formatting. I would like to be able to change the color of a cell (E62) to green if it is less than another cell (E64) and if that is false I want to change it (E62) to red if it is greater than the the other cell (E64).

Hopefully that was easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making two rules:

1. LessThan =E64, BackgroundColor green, Range E62
2. GreaterThan =E64, BackgroundColor red, Range E62

[image]

Comment: I was missing the "equals" portion of the rule. Much better! Thank you!